# Adding action to save_post, post needs to be saved twice for function to work

Tags: customization, wp-update-post, terms

I have written the following function which copies all post terms from the "tribe_events_cat" taxonomy to the "categoria" taxonomy when the post is saved. There is a bug where in order for the terms to be copied, I need to click "update" twice (i.e. save the post twice).

I believe this happens because when I call `get_the_terms`, the post has not been saved yet.

Is there any way around that, so that `get_the_terms` gets the terms from the newly updated post?

```
   function bam_save_event_cat( $post_id ) {
        $taxonomy = 'categoria';

        $tribe_cats = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'tribe_events_cat');

        foreach($tribe_cats as $tribe_cat) {
            if( empty($tribe_cat->name) ) continue;
            $catname = $tribe_cat->name;
            $cats[] = $catname;
        }
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cats, $taxonomy );
    }

    function bam_save_event($post_id) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return;

        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
            return;

        if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'tribe_events' ) {
            remove_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );
            wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id ) );
            add_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );

            bam_save_event_cat( $post_id );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a stab in the dark, but have you tried using the `set_object_terms` hook for your `bam_save_event_cat` function?

```
function bam_save_event_cat( $post_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy, $append, $old_tt_ids ) {
    $taxonomy = 'categoria';

    $tribe_cats = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'tribe_events_cat');

    foreach($tribe_cats as $tribe_cat) {
        if( empty($tribe_cat->name) ) continue;
        $catname = $tribe_cat->name;
        $cats[] = $catname;
    }
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cats, $taxonomy );
}

function bam_save_event($post_id) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    if(get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'tribe_events' ) {
        remove_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );
        wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_id ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );

        add_action( 'set_object_terms', 'bam_save_event_cat', 10, 6 );
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event' );
```

Comment: I had my fingers crossed but no, it didn't work at all. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: This is a great tip, and it works. Especially helpful if you're trying to intercept a change to a WooCommerce product's shipping class (which is saved as taxonomy terms)

Answer (score 1):

I think that I have encountered the same problem.

You have to set a higher priority than the default of 10 to your save_post action. The priority is specified as the third argument when adding an action as explained [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)

Like :

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'bam_save_event', 99 );
```